# Write some chinese characters on a book type document

Tags: latex, cjk, pdflatex, texstudio, spanish

I'm trying to write a book type document and I need to put some chinese characters in it. I read an answer to a question in this page, but it doesn't work to me. Language of the document is spanish.

My system is TeXstudio 4.6.3 (git 4.6.3) usingo Qt Version 6.5.2, compiled with Qt 6.5.2 R.

Compiler I use is pdflatex

Mi code is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage\[spanish\]{babel}
\usepackage\[latin1\]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{CJKutf8} %chinese characters
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Titulo}
\author{Autor}
\date{}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter

\input{prologo.tex}
\tableofcontents

\input{prologo.tex}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}你好吗 李爽\\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to put some chinese characters in my chapters documents and to view that in the generated pdf document.

Comment: You may try to use `ctex` package to write Chinese characters in your document: https://ctan.org/pkg/ctex